# SQL query to filter out if a flag is disabled

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with values that look something like this:

```
user_id | value | disabled
--------------------------
        | hello | false
   15   | hello | true
```

Where rows without a user_id are automatically generated with a default value of `disabled=false`

Users can then select values to disable so that those words will not appear in the list which is only visible to them.

My goal is to be able to return a combination of all system-generated values plus all the values a user has set, where the values aren't disabled.

The query currently looks something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (value)
user_id, value, disabled
FROM table
WHERE value LIKE '%%'
AND disabled = false
AND (user_id IS NULL OR user_id=15)
ORDER BY value, user_id;
```

However, with this query, it will still return `hello` since even though it sees that the user-generated has a value of `disabled=true`, it will still pass the system-generated one where the `disabled` is set to `false`.

What it should do is that since it sees a user-generated value that is disabled, it shouldn't return the system-generated one anymore.

Any ideas or suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT value
FROM table t
WHERE value LIKE '%%' AND
      disabled = false AND
      (user_id IS NULL OR user_id = 15) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t2 WHERE t2.value = t.value and t2.disabled = true);
```